# What is the Modulus of a Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across the following:

"Let f be continuously differentiable with Lipschitz gradient, i.e.,

$ ||\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) - \nabla f(\mathbf{y})|| \leq L||(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y})|| $

where L is the modulus of the Hessian (if exists)."

What is the modulus of a matrix? Is it the same thing as the determinant?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As [linear operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) $\nabla f$ has a so-called [operator norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm). In your case this is $L$

Comment: @Norbert Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A modulus of a matrix A = sqrt(A'A). Since A'A is always positive semidefinite, we can talk about the square root of it. Here, the square root of a positive semidefinite matrix is defined as the unique X which is also positive semidefinite and X^2 = A'A.