# Show that |detA|= det|A|

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that for a square matrix $A$, $|\det A| = \det|A|$, where $|A| = \sqrt{A^tA}$ is denoted as the modulus of A.

May I get a hint as to where to start this proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The modulus of $A$ is a positive semidefinite matrix $|A|$ such that $|A|^2=A^TA$ (or the hermitian transpose, if $A$ has complex entries). Then
$$
(\det |A|)^2=\det(|A|^2)=\det(A^TA)=(\det A)^2
$$
Since $|A|$ is positive semidefinite, its determinant is $\ge0$.

Comment: I interepreted it as modulus as in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214423/what-is-the-modulus-of-a-matrix) question, meaning the unique matrix $X$ such that $X^2 = A^tA$.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for noting

Answer (score 1):

$|det(A)|^2 = det(A^TA) = det(|A|^2) = (det|A|)^2 \Rightarrow |det(A)| = det|A|$